# How can I pass arguments inside that method?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm using the library turtle.
It has the [onkey](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html?highlight=logo#turtle.onkey) command, as specified:

```
turtle.onkeypress(fun, key=None)
Parameters:
fun – a function with no arguments or None
key – a string: key (e.g. “a”) or key-symbol (e.g. “space”)
```

However, I need to pass an argument. Was there any way to do this?

My code:

**menuInitial.py**

```
class MenuInitial(menu.Menu):
        [...]
    def itemInput(self):
        turtle.Screen().onkey(menu.Menu.itemUp(self), "Up")
        turtle.Screen().listen()
```

**menu.py**

```
class Menu(drawingGeometric.rectangle):
    [...]
    def itemUp(self):
        self.turtle.left(90)
        position.position.forwardWithoutPen(self, 16)
        self.turtle.right(90)
```

As can be seen, the "MenuInitial" class is heir to the "Menu". I'm learning object orientation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you should just do this:

```
class MenuInitial(menu.Menu):
        [...]
    def itemInput(self):
        turtle.Screen().onkey(self.itemUp, "Up")
        turtle.Screen().listen()
```

Because you're passing `itemUp` as a bound instance method (`self.itemUp`) to `onkey` instead of as an unbound method (`menu.Menu.itemUp`), `self` will automatically be passed as the first argument. You can do this because `MenuInitial` is a child of `Menu`, so they share the same internal state.

If for some reason you *did* need to pass another argument to `itemUp`, you could use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial

[...]

    def itemInput(self):
        func = partial(self.itemUp, "some_argument")
        turtle.Screen().onkey(func, "Up")
        turtle.Screen().listen()
```

Then you could have this:

```
class Menu(drawingGeometric.rectangle):
    [...]
    def itemUp(self, argument):
        print(argument) # This will print "some_argument"
        self.turtle.left(90)
        position.position.forwardWithoutPen(self, 16)
        self.turtle.right(90)
```

Comment: I did not know this possibility. It worked perfectly. However, **in another situation** it was not possible to pass `self`, would have any idea?